I use 3 seperate macros to sum a total E col wch is 200 rows, 1700 rows, 3500 rows, etc. Can i have all 3 in single Run
Hello everyone & thanks for allowing me to ask a question.
I am totally new to excel VBA and hubly ask your advise on a issue i am facing.
I managed to get a VBA to caount sum total on column E for 200 rows on my excel sheet. This is fine, but if the column E is excessive ( more than 2500 or 4000 rows) then im usung seperate Modules to run the same macro, 1st macro for upto 500 rows, 2nd macro for upto 2000 rows, 3rd macro for upto 4000 rows, etc.etc.
i thought if excel could count the Last Row and then automatically select the macro to Run, depending on the size of LastRow in col E. rather than manually checking the last row and then running the code based on the last row size.
Please let me know if i need to provide any more details, my humble request to guide me in the above question. Thanks in advance.
Basically i increased the E col as E2:E200 to E2:E2000 and copy-pasted in Module2, and E2:E4000 and copy-pasted in Module3 based on the last row of E column.

What is wrong with sum(E:E) ?

Yes im aware of sum(E:E) code. Actually, my requierement is to find the last cell in E:E and do a sum total., which i alredy have working.  But if the rows increase, it only totals upto a fixed number of rows and ignores the extra rows counting. CellCheck:
If ActiveCell.Row < 2 Then GoTo EndOfSubroutine
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select 'Move up
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then GoTo TestEachCell
If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 Then GoTo TestEachCell
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
GoTo CellCheck
